# Let $X = $ {$S : S$ is a set and $S \notin S$}. Is {$1, 2$} $\in X$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

And a follow-up question:
Is $X \in X$, where $X$ is as defined previously?

I'm not sure about my reasoning. I think that since no set can be an element of itself, $X$ can contain any set, hence {$1, 2$} $\in X$.

As for the next question... Well, is this exercise supposed to make one think about Cantor's paradox or am I missing something and there's a "straightforward" answer?

Comment: The only elements in $\{1,2\}$ are $1$ and $2$. It is not a set of sets, so no set can be in it. The second sentence in your second line makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: Russel's paradox, not Cantor's paradox.  Yes, $\{1,2\}\in X$ (*if you allow this notation despite the fact that $X$ is seen not to be a set at all*).  As for whether $X\in X$ or $X\notin X$, neither are possible, hence the paradox.  The resolution of this paradox is to agree then that $X$ must not be a "set" in the first place, but rather something more exotic.

Comment: You are probably intended to check that $\{1,2\} \notin X$ directly using the definition, rather than by using the fact that no set is an element of itself. Yes, the second is supposed to make you think about paradoxes.

Comment: @TheCount $1$ is defined in set theory as $\{\emptyset\}$ while $2=\{\emptyset, 1\}$.Then $\{1,2\}$ is actually a set of sets.

Comment: How do you define $1$ and $2$ would have immense repercussions to the answer.

Comment: What do you mean by "as defined previously"? MSE is not a soap opera.

Comment: @RobArthan the title

Comment: @Holo: The title is **not** part of the question (and "defined previously"is not a very good way of saying "as defined above"). The body of an MSE question should be self-contained.

Comment: @RobArthan I agree with that but I think you should have said this instead, Imo how you said it is kind of rude(I can't speak in place in OP tho)

Comment: @Holo: I genuinely didn't know what the OP meant by "as defined previously" and incorrectly suspected he or she was referring to another question (hence my reference to MSE as soap opera). If you conflate mild sarcasm with rudeness, I despair for you.

Comment: @Dog_69 is that a canonical thing? If so, good to know. thanks.

Comment: @TheCount I don't know if it is canonical. The definition was stated firstly by von Neumann and hence is called nowadays as von Neumann's ordinals (see [Wiki](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number)). As far as I know, it is the usual definition of ordinals in modern set theory, but there are others, as you can see in the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check whether $\{1,2\}\in X$ you should ask yourself: $$\mbox{is }\{1,2\}\in\{1,2\}?$$

The second question is a bit more interesting, if $X$ is a set then let's see what are the options;

If $X\in X$ then, by the construction of $X$, we have that $X\notin X$.

If $X\notin X$ then $X$ answer the criteria to "enter" $X$, hence $X\in X$.

Both cases leads to construction thus $X$ is not a set but a proper class!

This is indeed suppose to make you think about *Russell's paradox*(there is a thing called *Cantor's paradox* but it is different thing, you'll probably learn about it when you'll get to cardinal numbers)